# How do I use the same data to create multiple files?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to create two files with the same data.  One file to use for updating live web data and the other as a log.  One file needs to be appended to and updated frequently. I can create the log fine but am struggling on how to handle the data for the second file.

I have tried using a 'with open' statement for the log file.  When I try reading this into a live web page, it shows me the data that has been logged previously, and updates the data only when the file is closed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

#Solar Panel Script 1.0

#Set pin for Pump Relay Signal (PR = pin 29)

#Set up Pump Relay BCM5 (pin 29) as output pin in off position
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup (5, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Load Hot Water Tank (HWT), Solar Panel (SP), and Outside Temp (OT) with OWFS

#Create CSV File for temperature data
from time import sleep, strftime, time
with open("/var/www/html/data.csv", "a") as log:
        while True:
                with open ("/mnt/1wire/28.C14777910F02/temperature", "r") as myfile:
                        HWT=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
                        myfile.close()
                with open ("/mnt/1wire/28.390877910402/temperature", "r") as myfile2:
                        SP=myfile2.read().replace('\n', '')
                        myfile.close()
                log.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), str(HWT), str(SP)))

#Solar Hot Water Heater Module
#Turns on PR only if SP is 10F hotter than HWT.  Checks OT for frezing temps, if less than 33, PR is off.
                print ('hot water: ' + HWT)
                print ('solar panel: '+ SP)
                flt_HWT = float(HWT)
                flt_SP = float(SP)

                if flt_HWT > 170:
                        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.LOW) #Pump Relay Off
                if flt_SP > (flt_HWT + 10):
                        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.HIGH) #Pump Relay On
                state = GPIO.input(5)
                print state
                sleep(20) #10 Minutes = 600
```

I expected the log file to allow me to collect data from it while it was open.

Answer (score 0):

```
log.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), str(HWT), str(SP)))
```

This is where you are writing the log. You can simply include another with open() statement here

```
with open("secondfile.log") as secfile:
    log.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), str(HWT), str(SP))) ##original log file can be here
    secfile.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), str(HWT), str(SP))) ##and here you are wrighting the second file.
```

However if you are wrighting multiple files it would be better to stick them into a function of their own.

```
def write_file(text, filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            file.write(text)
        return True
    except:
        return False ##include any other exception stuff here
```

now you can use

```
success = write_file("log text", "filename.log")
if success:
     success = write_file("log2 text", "filename2.log")
if success:
    print("Yey both files have been written to")
else:
    print("Awww, there was an error writing to the file")
```